# Blackberry splash screen wait issue

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I'm trying to launch a splash screen for a few seconds and then close it and launch the second screen.

For some reason, the code executes the "sleep" before showing the splash page and the splash page appears only for a fraction of a second and the second screen appears immediately. In other words when I click on the app icon, it waits for 2 seconds, then shows and immediately hides splash and jumps to HomeScreen.

I've tried many different combinations including `invokeAndWait()`, call backs and threads inside the Splash class but to no avail.

I've gone through many posts on SO as well.

Please note that I do not want the splash page to open the next screen; the launcher of the splash page (`AppStart`) should launch the next screen.

Please suggest a solution.

Code:

```
public class AppStart extends UiApplication 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AppStart app = new AppStart();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public AppStart() {
        final Splash splashscreen = new Splash();
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(splashscreen); 
            }
        });
        Thread waitthread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run()
            {               
                try {
                    sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                finally
                {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(splashscreen); 
                        }
                    });
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new HomeScreen()); 
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };  
        waitthread.run();
    }

}
```

Splash

```
public class Splash extends MainScreen {
    public Splash()
    {
        Bitmap bgImg = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("480x320-SplashScreen.png");
        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bgImg);
        getMainManager().setBackground(bg);
    }   
}
```

Comment: refer this - http://rincethomas.blogspot.in/2013/09/splash-loading-screen-in-blackberry.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
waitthread.run();
```

That is the problem. You are not starting a new thread, but hogging the main thread instead by callyng a method that sleeps it. Replace that line with this one:

```
waitthread.start();
```

And it should work.